# Can I cast Bestow Curse twice at greater than 5th level on the same creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stacking

Is it possible to cast *bestow curse* twice on the same target using a spell slot of 5th level or higher (so it doesn't require concentration) to bestow different curses? I can't see anything in the [spell description](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Bestow%20Curse#content) that forbids this, but it seems like it could be cheese. I'm especially interested in bestowing the "Wis save or suck" (3rd effect on the spell page) and imposing disadvantage on Wisdom saves and ability checks (first effect on the link above).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No, the effects don't stack over the same duration

According to the rule on [combining magical effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects) (PHB, page 205), the effects of different spells add together but the effects of multiple instances of the same spell do not.

> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don’t combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap.

Instead the most powerful version of the spell would from the casting. If they were the same spell slot level used, then it would be up to the DM in this case to determine which one is active on a creature.

This assumes the creature fails both saves and what you are going for is for the creature to make disadvantage wisdom saves to be able to take an action.

Comment: I assumed that the creature failed both and that the person wanted to have them roll at disadvantage for the wisdom save to take an action. Which the answer is no in that case.

Comment: Does that also apply if two different people cast the spell?

Comment: Yes, the link actually uses that as an example.

Comment: Damn, that's disappointing.

Comment: Bestow Curse seems like it may be a special case that doesn't fit as neatly into the rule you are citing, which probably assumes that the spell in question will have the same effect with both castings, which is not the case in the OP's question.

Comment: If that is how a DM wants to run the spell that is fine. However 8+ hours of save or suck at disadvantage is pretty strong.

Comment: @user39671: Nothing in the rule assumes that the spell will have the same effect - it simply says the effect of the same spell cast multiple times won't combine.

Comment: BTW, the [2018 PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) slightly modifies the quoted portion by adding this to the end of the quote: "Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap, **or the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap.**"