# What is the strongest minion a necromancers Command undead ability can control?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, necromancy

I am currently a lv13 Necromancer and my 14th lv ability lets me control 1 undead. I want to know what the strongest official undead creature is with an int of 11 or less so I can start tracking 1 down now. I've seen this question asked before but I haven't found an answer that doesn't include using the spell feeblemind which is something I don't have access to. Just to clarify by strongest I mean I'm just looking for the highest CR

Comment: Related: [What is the most powerful permanent undead follower you can get?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130248/41726)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be the **Nightwalker**, from Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes. CR20, with an Intelligence score of 6, and no legendary resistances.

[image]

The only undead with higher CR are the Lich, Illithilich, Jarad vod Savo, and Lady Illmarrow, all of which have 20+ intelligence.